# My sprite is walking on air because it thinks it is touching a platform but it's not..?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying a lot to get my code working but my sprite isn't being affected by gravity and when I tried some print() to see what was going wrong it seems as though my sprite thinks it's touching the platform at all times when touching it once..? [Image to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Ds6.png)

Here's the code:

```
tx   = 64
ty   = 64

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
    self.movex = 0 # move along X
    self.movey = 0 # move along Y
    self.isJumping = True
    self.isFalling = True

  def gravity(self):
    if self.isJumping == True:
      self.movey += 3.2

  def update(self):
    platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platform_list, False)
    for p in platform_hit_list:
      self.isJumping = False  # stop jumping
      self.movey = 0

      if self.rect.bottom <= p.rect.bottom:
          self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
      else:
          self.movey += 3.2
    
    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex  
    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

class Level:
  def platform(lvl, tilesX, tilesY):
    platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    platformLocation = []
    i = 0
    if lvl == 1:
      platformLocation.append((1000, height - tilesY - 100, 0))
      while i < len(platformLocation):
        j = 0
        while j <= platformLocation[i][2]:
          platform = Platform((platformLocation[i][0] + (j * tilesX)), platformLocation[i][1], tilesX, tilesY, 'platform.png')
          platform_list.add(platform)
          j = j + 1
        print('run' + str(i) + str(platformLocation[i]))
        i = i + 1
    return platform_list

platform_list = Level.platform(1, tx, ty)
```

Happy to some solutions and explanations to the problem

Comment: Please post an actual [mcve] if you want actual help.

Comment: I believe that this is better? I'm sorry if it isn't, first time asking on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show has the player start with `self.isJumping = True`, but once it gets set to `False` in the `update` function (when there is a collision), it never gets set to `True` again. That's why you don't fall if you walk off the edge of a platform.

You probably want to set `isJumping` to `True` before you loop over the collided platforms, so that if there were no collisions, it will stay `True`.

```
def update(self):
    self.isJumping = True        # we're in the air by default
    platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platform_list, False)
    for p in platform_hit_list:
        self.isJumping = False   # unless we collide with something
        ...
```

If there can be many kinds of collisions in your game (e.g. walking or jumping into the sides of walls), you may need more sophisticated collision response code than this, since only collisions in which the platform is right near the player's feet should make them stop falling (jumping into a wall or ceiling would be very odd otherwise).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! Now that you've told me it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
tx   = 64
ty   = 64

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
    self.movex = 0 # move along X
    self.movey = 0 # move along Y
    self.isJumping = True
    self.isFalling = True

  def gravity(self):
    if self.isJumping == True:
      self.movey += 3.2

def update(self):
    self.isJumping = True   
    platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platform_list, False)
    for p in platform_hit_list:
        self.isJumping = False 
        self.movey = 0

      if self.rect.bottom <= p.rect.bottom:
          self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
      else:
          self.movey += 3.2
    
    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex  
    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

class Level:
  def platform(lvl, tilesX, tilesY):
    platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    platformLocation = []
    i = 0
    if lvl == 1:
      platformLocation.append((1000, height - tilesY - 100, 0))
      while i < len(platformLocation):
        j = 0
        while j <= platformLocation[i][2]:
          platform = Platform((platformLocation[i][0] + (j * tilesX)), platformLocation[i][1], tilesX, tilesY, 'platform.png')
          platform_list.add(platform)
          j = j + 1
        print('run' + str(i) + str(platformLocation[i]))
        i = i + 1
    return platform_list

platform_list = Level.platform(1, tx, ty)
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes more sense now.